# How to read Microsoft Project (MPP) file in .NET Core or PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, import, ms-project, mpp

How can I import Microsoft Project file (MPP) data into PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu OS directly or using .NET Core application?
I read about mpxj plugin but it only supports ASP.NET not .NET Core. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

MPXJ 10.0.0 now supports .NET Core, so you should now be able to use it in the way you describe in your question. Alternatively you could create write your application in Java or Python and use MPXJ from either of those languages.